# Sorcery - signed_in_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I can get

```
<% if current_user %>
```

to work. However I would like to be able to use statments like

```
<% if current_user=(user) %>
```

or something like that. How can I do this with Sorcery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use an assignment operator where you need a comparison operator. It should probably be like this:

```
<%= if @user == current_user %>
  <!-- Do stuff -->
<% end %>
```

Remember you need to get access to the `@user` instance variable by assigning it in your controller action:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```